# Convert IDL structure with conformant array to header

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, rpc, midl

I need to pass via Microsoft RPC structure with conformant array. This is how I write it in IDL:

```
struct BarStruct
{
  byte a;
  int b;
  byte c;
long lArraySize;
[size_is(lArraySize)] char achArray[*];
};
```

Generated header:

```
struct BarStruct
    {
    byte a;
    int b;
    byte c;
    long lArraySize;
    char achArray[ 1 ];
    } ;
```

Why achArray is fixed length of 1? How to pass array with for example 10 elements to it?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
BarStruct* p = (BarStruct*)CoTaskMemAlloc(
    offsetof(BarStruct, achArray) + 10*sizeof(char));
```

Basically, you need to allocate memory as if the structure had `achArray[10]` member at the end. `offsetof(BarStruct, achArray)` gives you the size of the fixed part of the structure, up to but not including `achArray`. To this, you add variable size of the array.